# Can't enqueue scripts in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the Divi Wordpress theme but I want to build a custom home page which will be this Bootstrap template: https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/BizPage/

The website is: https://affiliation2k.com/

I've created a child theme and in `functions.php` and the styles are working with this code:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'homepage-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'thisanimation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/animate/animate.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib//bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'this-font-aweosome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'ionicons',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/lightbox/css/lighbox.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/lightbox/css/lighbox.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-green', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.green.min.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

but, my scripts won't load. I've tried this one:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.1', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-bundle-jss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('home-main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', false );
wp_enqueue_script('counter-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/counterup/counterup.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('easing-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/easing/easing.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true   );
wp_enqueue_script('isotope-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script('lightbox-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
wp_enqueue_script('wow-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/wow/wow.min.js', array(), '', true  );
wp_enqueue_script('carousel-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
wp_enqueue_script('hover-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/superfish/hoverIntent.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
wp_enqueue_script('super-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/superfish/superfish.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script('waypoints-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
wp_enqueue_script('touchSwipe', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Additionally: 
`get_template_directory_uri()` is returning me:
website/wp-content/themes/Divi and

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is returning me:
website/wp-content/themes/Divi-child

Comment: look the source code, you will see that scripts are loaded.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I wonder why the animations are not shown on my website like on https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/BizPage/

Comment: The scripts are enqueuing as they should, so I would re-word your question to ask about the animations if that's your issue. The two are not related.